# What is the package name for the Ubuntu MATE "compact menu"?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, menu

I installed `mate-desktop` and `mate-desktop-environment` on a stock Ubuntu 18.04 system for testing, but I didn't get my preferred choice of menus to add to the panel, the "Compact Menu".

If you install a full-up Ubuntu MATE system, you get this choice.  Here is a screenshot showing that install with the Compact Menu installed, the help screen, and some other menu choices.

[image]

Here's a screenshot from the test system showing that the Compact Menu is not a choice.

[image]

What package do I need to install to get the Compact Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brief search in the source code gives a clue that such menus are provided by [`mate-panel` package](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=Compact+Menu&literal=1).

There was a [commit in `mate-panel`](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/commit/c50e4bd3aaf65a27a57df75d3141428ac6f686ec#diff-5aec13660e9adae6e34d55f9e832028cc094f57db9c7fce5190c5d0bf882c2edR153) by Matrin Wimpress from Oct 7, 2019 which introduces the rename from "Main Menu" to "Compact Menu".

So we have the following:

- on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and earlier it is really named "Main Menu"

  > [image: <= 18.04 LTS]
- on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS and newer it is named "Compact Menu"

  > [image: >= 20.04 LTS]

Comment: Thanks, you are 100% correct. That's what I needed.